# Unity LightDM background and gnome "lockscreen"

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, desktop-background

I've recently added Gnome3.18 in my Ubuntu 16.04, but I decided to keep with lightdm-unity-greeter, for some reason it uses my background picture in the login screen instead of my "lock screen" picture as one would expect.
How can I make it use the user lock screen picture?

Comment: so your login screen and lock screens are lightdm and desktop environment is GNOME not unity rite?

Comment: Correct, but I'm using lightdm-unity-greeter instead of lightdm-gtk-greeter or lightdm-kde-greeter